# Why is my code not working?.... It seems error in the scanf and printf but I'm not sure

Tags: c

·Why is my code not working?.... It seems error in the scanf and printf but I'm not sure
Somebody could help me?.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
     FILE * archivo;
    int num,i,c,f,k;
    archivo = fopen("fichero.txt","w");
    printf("Generador de conversion de temperatura");
    printf("Ingrese el Numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    i = 1;
    c = 0;
    printf(" No\t°C\t °F\t  K\n");
    fprintf(archivo," No\t°C\t °F\t  K\n");
    
    while (i<=num) {
    f = c*1.800+32;
    k = c+273.15;
        
    printf(" ","%d",i,"\t","%d",c,"\t","%d",f,"\t","%d",k,"\n");
    fprintf(archivo," ","%d",i,"\t","%d",c,"\t","%d",f,"\t","%d",k,"\n");
        
    i+=1;
    c+=1;
    }
    fclose(archivo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Include a description of the error in the question please. “Not working” is too vague.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The final `printf` and `fprintf` are incorrectly using the format string.  These functions take a single format string followed by a list of variables to insert into the format, one for each `%d` etc. that you use.  So you should rewrite these lines:

```
printf(" ","%d",i,"\t","%d",c,"\t","%d",f,"\t","%d",k,"\n");
fprintf(archivo," ","%d",i,"\t","%d",c,"\t","%d",f,"\t","%d",k,"\n");
```

as the following:

```
printf(" %d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, c, f, k);
fprintf(archivo," %d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, c, f, k);
```

Notice that there is one string with 4 `%d` specifiers in it and it is followed by a list of 4 variables to match.

As an aside, you are doing floating point math but then assigning it back to an int, which is truncating the values.  I'm not sure if this is what you intended, but you might want to use float/double values and then limit the number of decimal places accordingly, e.g. `%.2f` would print two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the error

```
printf(" %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \n", i, c, f, k);
fprintf(archivo," %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \n", i, c, f, k);
```

In printf statement variable that map the identifiers should come at the end as shown above.

**Full Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
     FILE * archivo;
    int num,i,c,f,k;
    archivo = fopen("fichero.txt","w");
    printf("Generador de conversion de temperatura");
    printf("Ingrese el Numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    i = 1;
    c = 0;
    printf(" No\t°C\t °F\t  K\n");
    fprintf(archivo," No\t°C\t °F\t  K\n");
    
    while (i<=num) {
    f = c*1.800+32;
    k = c+273.15;
        
    printf(" %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \n", i, c, f, k);    
    fprintf(archivo," %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \n", i, c, f, k);
        
    i+=1;
    c+=1;
    }
    fclose(archivo);
    return 0;
}
```